# Passing data to and from server using XML

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I need to design a web site in which data is passed to and from the server using XML. I got it how to transform data from database to XML and then to HTML, but I am not able to find how to pass data from client to server using XML. My webpages are designed using ASP. Is it possible to do pass data from client to server using XML. What are the things that are to be studied?

Comment: Hi, sapna. Welcome to Stackoverflow! I think you will have to give us some more details on the problem, for us to be able to be able to help. What is the concrete problem you are facing? Do you have some code that does not work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX might be the way to go.

AJAX can be used to pass your data between client and server in the XML format.